# NodeJS API concerns for iPhone

Tags: ios, node.js, authentication, linkedin-api

I am making an API in NodeJS that 'll be used by a website and iPhone native app at the same time.

It is supposed to authorize user using LinkedIn API. How can I do that with NodeJS API when iPhone native app is working on other end?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at passportjs.org

You should be able to do what you need with this library.